# Easiest way to deploy a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I finished my first ruby on rails application and I would like to put it up online.
What is the easiest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to use http://heroku.com/ they are by far one of the easiest ways to have an app running online in 5 mins.

Comment: What if the person wanted to deploy to their own server, without using github?  What would you recommend then?

Answer (score 2):

see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055682/good-ruby-on-rails-free-hosting